# Use different ruby version in one project in rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am building rails application using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 2.0.0

I have to use this http://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/samplecode.html library which support only ruby 1.9.2 , i tried it for ruby 2.0.0 but had no luck. It is working fine with ruby 1.9.3.

I don't want to downgrade to ruby 1.9.3, so is there any way so that I can use this library without downgrading , maybe using Rails Engine or building another Rails::API app in ruby 1.9.3 .

Any help or suggestion ?

Comment: No: one app, one ruby version.

Comment: A gem that only supports 1.9.2 is vastly outdated. There are some [great PDF gems](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/create-pdf-documents-ruby) in Ruby, pick one of those.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm I want to optimize my pdf (remove duplicate images etc ) to reduce size. do you know any such gem ?

Comment: @AnilMaurya Try [a Github search](https://github.com/search?l=Ruby&o=desc&q=pdf&ref=cmdform&s=stars&type=Repositories) for your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to Solve this problem by using Java library of PdfNet along with RJB.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a totally different application and then make HTTP API calls from one to the other, you could have the two applications running on different ruby versions. But it would be more performant if you didn't have to go over the network, and of course the cost of maintaining and running 2 applications is more than one.

Comment: No, I was saying it's one or the other. Either you have two applications and make HTTP API calls over the network, or you have one application and you don't have to go over the network. Sorry I was unclear :-/

Comment: I know that building two application and making HTTP API call will not be efficient and that's why I am asking If their is any way to use 2 Ruby version in one project.

Comment: No, there is not. I was saying you could use two ruby versions with two projects and that would allow you to do what you want to do with the tradeoff of some performance.

Comment: Thanks , Appreciate you help :)